# Problem when build Chromium to Android project

Tags: android, chromium

I'm having problems building chromium for Android (content_shell_apk)
build chromium to an android project

After finish

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md

I follow step like link below but cannot genergate project for me
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_studio.md#Extracting-srcjars

I used

```
build/android/gradle/generate_gradle.py \
--output-directory out/Default \
--project-dir ~/Projects/chromium_source/gradle_project \
--target '//chrome/android:chrome_public_apk'
```

Can anyone with experience help me?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJoNG.png

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60925815/edit) your question with more detail as to what steps you've done and what is missing or confusing. Also state on what OS/OS version you are building on.

Comment: i just update my question. Can you help me?